# Javascript index of for multiple values

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, indexing

Im having a multdimensional javascript arrays like this.

```
[
["9", "16", "19", "24", "29", "38"],
["9", "15", "19", "24", "29", "38"],
["10", "16", "19", "24", "29", "38"],
["9", "16", "17", "19", "24", "29", "39"],
["10", "16", "17", "19", "24", "29", "39"],
["9", "15", "21", "24", "29", "38"]

.......
.......
]
```

Around 40 to be exact

and im having an another array called check with the following values

```
 [9,10] //This is of size two for example,it may contain any number of elements BUT it only contains elements(digits) from the multidimensional array above
```

What i want is i need to make the multidimensional array unique based for the check array elements

1.Example if check array is `[15]`
Then multidimensional array would be

```
[
    ["9", "15", "19", "24", "29", "38"],
   //All the results which contain 15

]
```

2.Example if check array is `[15,21]`
Then multidimensional array would be

```
[
    ["9", "15", "21", "24", "29", "38"]
    //simply containing 15 AND 21.Please note previous example has only 15 in it not 21
    //I need an AND not an OR

]
```

I had tried the JavaScript IndexOf method BUt it is getting me an OR'ed result not AND

Thanks in Advance

Comment: _"Around 40 to be exact"_ - Ah, irony.

Comment: @nnnnnn ..hope you got the idea.if not ill explain more

Comment: Yes, you want to filter the original array to return all the child arrays that contain all of the elements in the check array. Except that your second example returns a child array not shown in your original, so maybe I don't understand. (My previous comment was just poking fun at your choice of words there.)

Comment: Yes ...@nnnnnn  The keyword is i needed an `AND` ed result :)

Comment: None of the rows in your sample array contain a "21" - is that just a typo?

Comment: @nnnnnn: That is probably one of his exactly around 40 ones :)

Comment: Thats why i mentioned around 40 results..it may contain in later lines

Comment: @nnnnnn question edited please have a look

Comment: should it be in the exact order ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var mainArray = [ /* your array here */ ],
    check = ["15", "21"],
    result;

result = mainArray.filter(function(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++)
        if (val.indexOf(check[i]) === -1)
            return false;    
    return true;
});

console.log(result);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Dq6YR/

Note that `.filter()` is not supported by IE until version 9, but [you can fix that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

Answer (score 4):

Using `.filter` and `.every`, you can filter the rows for which every argument is apparent in the row:

```
var filter = function(args) {
  return arr.filter(function(row) {
    return args.every(function(arg) {
      return ~row.indexOf(String(arg));  // [15] should search for ["15"]
    });
  });
};
```

`.every` effectively does an `AND` operation here; for `OR` you could use `.some` instead. Those array functions are available on newer browsers.

Comment: what is up with that tilde (`~`) there? :/
`~row`

Answer (score 2):

There is also a solution that is not using `filter()` or `every()`:

```
// function

function AndArray(start, check) {

    this.stripArray = function(element, array) {
        var _array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                if(element == array[i][j]) _array.push(array[i]);
        return _array;
        }

    for(var k = 0; k < start.length; k++)
        if(start.length > 0) start = this.stripArray(check[k], start);

    return start;

    }

// use

var check = [15, 21];

var start= [[ 15, 6 , 8], [3, 21, 56], [15, 3, 21]];

console.log(AndArray(start, check));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```js
var checkURL = function (url) {
  var final = false;
  if (url.indexOf('jpg') > -1) {
    final = true
  }

  if (url.indexOf('jpeg') > -1) {
    final = true
  }

  if (url.indexOf('gif') > -1) {
    final = true
  }

  if (url.indexOf('png') > -1) {
    final = true
  }

  return final
}
```